# Why do I get KeyError: "MIGRATION_COMMANDS" when I upload my project to Divio Server?

Tags: django, divio

I would like to know why I can't deploy my Django project in a Divio Server, since I get the error:

```
File "/virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/aldryn_djang/cli.py",line 51, in migrate
cmds = ctx_obj['settings']['MIGRATION_COMMANDS']
KeyError: 'MIGRATION_COMMANDS'
```

Comment: This appears of the Divio thing than Django.

Comment: aldryn is expecting a `MIGRATION_COMMANDS` entry in your configuration. Check the [docs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aldryn-django) about the required config files.